# Android SwitchCase inside onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, switch-statement

I am trying use a switch case. But it says i cant pass a string :(

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    Log.i("Harsha", selection);

    switch (selection) {
    case "Compose":

        break;
    case "Inbox":

        break;
    case "Drafts":

        break;
    case "Sent":

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

The error is

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The switch expression must be of type
>   char, byte, short, or int. All case
>   labels must be constant
>   expressions—the expressions must
>   contain only literals or named
>   constants initialized with constant
>   expressions—and must be assignable to
>   the type of the switch expression.

It is what it is! Java doesn't allow you to pass String for a switch case statment, infact, the new Proposal was possibly rejected. ( read in a blog somewhere, i'm sorry, don't have the source)

But it doesn't mean you can't do it by another method.

Alternatives

1) Use the position of the listitem, rather than the string.

2) Use [Enum](http://www.xefer.com/2006/12/switchonstring)

3) Store it in a `Map<String,Integer>` (or even an array), and use the Value in the SWitch Case

EDIT: Personally, i would add 4 constants and do it this way

```
final int MENU_COMPOSE = 0; //should be equal to the index in your array.
final int MENU_INBOX = 1;
final int MENU_DRAFTS = 2;
final int MENU_SENT = 3;

switch (position) {
case MENU_COMPOSE: //Compose, add comments never the less.

    break;
case  MENU_INBOX: //Inbox

    break;
case  MENU_DRAFTS: //Drafts

    break;
case  MENU_SENT: //Sent

    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: Can u give me an example of how to use position of the list item to do this ?

Comment: @Harsha, Are your menu items constant? If so then `switch(position)` and `Compose=0,Inbox=1,Drafts=2,Sent=3` would you like me to elaborate?

Comment: @st0le yes they are populated from an array. and they are fixed. am still learning :)

Comment: but i am using the Array to populate the List View :(

Comment: @Harsha, Doesn't matter, it'll still work....you dont have to change that part of the code...maybe you should add your own code. I'll post it accodingly.

Comment: @st0le thanks you. Is there any resource i can go thru for a crash course ? i dont knw Java. i am learning java and android simultaneously

Comment: @Harsha, it seems you haven't got the hang of the syntax yet...you may start with http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/, good luck :)

Comment: @st0le :) thanks :) is there a way i can contact you off stackoverflow ?

Comment: @Harsha, Just leave a comment with @st0le, to this answer or any i answered...or just post a question, i'll be lurking around. :) I'm sure the others will be equally helpfull

Comment: @st0le you  saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Java `switch case` operator only accepts integer values. Use `if else` instead.